# How to create dynamic folder selection parameter in Jankins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use Jenkins as a tool as an automation build.
So, I need to create a pipline with parameter that helps me to select an appropriate directory where I start a build batch file.
By the moment, I have found how to select a directory as a parameter by usage of Extensible Choice plugin.
But it allows me to select a folder at one level, but I need to go deeper and get an oportunity to select via multilevel directory levels.
For example, select directory at level1 and than at level2 and finaly at level3. 
Could you please give me any advise how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use groovy script in pipeline job to dynamically assign the directory

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have tried to find any similar example of code or plugin but haven't been succeed with this. 
So, I have decided to do that based on a standard groovy syntax. Here is the code:

```
node {stage "Directories list output"
          def dirname  = getdirlist()       
            echo dirname}
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
@NonCPS
  def getdirlist() {def initialPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(initialPath);
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        int result = fc.showOpenDialog( null );
            switch ( result ){case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
                    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    def path =  fc.getCurrentDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                    def outputpath="path="+path+"\nfile name="+file.toString();
                    break;
                    case JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION:
                    case JFileChooser.ERROR_OPTION:
                    break;}
  return outputpath}
```

I can't make it work. I have some suspitions that Jenkins pipeline doesn't allow to open a standard Java file dialog. What can be another aproach to my task?